# Populating dropdown list is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this **script for regions**:

```
function LoadRegions() {
    var region = $('#RegionID');
    alert("test");
    var url = "../Account/GetRegions";
    $.getJSON(url, { countryId: $('#CountryID').val() }, function (response) {
        // clear and add default (null) option 

        region.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text("Please select"));


        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            region.append($('<option></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
        }

    });
}
```

In **view** i have:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectCountryId, Model.Countries, @Translator.Translate("PLEASE_SELECT"), new { id = "CountryID", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "LoadRegions();"})
```

In **controller** i have:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetRegions(int countryId) // return a JsonResult
    {
        IUserManager manager = UserFactory.GetUserManager(WebConfiguration.DefaultTerminalId);
        var model = manager.GetRegions(countryId);
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My idea is that when user choose one country that i get regions but for some reason this is not working.any help? I get alert that is in function but nothing else

EDIT:my routes

```
   routes.MapRoute(
               name: "DefaultAppWithLanguages",
               url: "app/{languageId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { language = "en", controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
               constraints: new { languageId = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApp",
                url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { language = "en", controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { language = "en", controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Try changing the url to `var url = '@Url.Action("GetRegions", "Account")';` to ensure its correctly generated.

Comment: now i get this in console GET http://localhost:60789/@Url.Action(%22GetRegions%22,%20%22Account%22)?countryId=4 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have areas in the app? And what was the error before the change?

Comment: i didnt get any error before...thats why i added alert and on change i get alert...what areas? i have countries and onchange it shoud populate regions

Comment: No I mean route areas :). If `var url = '@Url.Action("GetRegions", "Account")';` is not working there is something odd with your routing. Add add additional alerts inside the `$.getJSON()` function to see what the `response` is

Comment: i edited my post..to show u my route

Comment: i dont get anything inside $.getJson

Comment: Are you even hitting the controller method?

Comment: no...so its because url is wrong??

Comment: Just try it with `var url = /app/en/Account/GetRegions;`

Comment: thats it ... its because this "app":)

Comment: can i ask u one more thing?

Comment: how can i modified this script so when user choose countrie to get first element in script and not this "Please select" ? :)

Comment: After the `for` loop - add `region.val(response[0].Id);`. Alternatively, just delete the `append($('<option></option>').val('').text("Please select"));` so its not generated in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on you routes, `var url = "../Account/GetRegions";` will not hit the method. You need to change it to be

```
var url = '/app/en/Account/GetRegions';
```